# Creating function to read data set and columns and displyaing nrow

Tags: r, dataframe

I am struggling a bit with a probably fairly simple task. I wanted to create a function that has arguments of dataframe(df), column names of dataframe(T and R), value of the selected column of dataframe(a and b). I know that the function reads the dataframe. but , I don't know how the columns are selected. I'm getting an error.

```
fun <- function(df,T,a,R,b)
{
col <- ds[c("x","y")]
omit <- na.omit(col)
data1 <- omit[omit$x == 'a',]
data2 <- omit[omit$x == 'b',]
nrow(data2)/nrow(data1)
}
fun(jugs,Place,UK,Price,10)
```

I'm new to r language. So, please help me.

Comment: In the first line did you intend to use `df`, `T`, and `R`? Namely, `col <- df[c(T,R)];`? And in the third and fourth lines, did you intend to use `T`, `R`, `a`, and `b`? Namely, `data1 <- omit[omit[[T]]==a,]; data2 <- omit[omit[[R]]==b];`?

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors you're making.

```
col <- ds[c("x","y")]
```

What are x and y? Presumably they're arguments that you're passing, but you specify T and R in your function, not x and y.

```
data1 <- omit[omit$x == 'a',]
data2 <- omit[omit$x == 'b',]
```

Again, presumably, you want a and b to be arguments you passed to the function, but you specified 'a' and 'b' which are specific, not general arguments. Also, I assume that second "omit$x" should be "omit$y" (or vice versa). And actually, since you just made this into a new data frame with two columns, you can just use the column index.

```
nrow(data2)/nrow(data1)
```

You should print this line, or return it. Either one should suffice.

```
fun(jugs,Place,UK,Price,10)
```

Finally, you should use quotes on Place, UK, and Price, at least the way I've done it.

```
fun <- function(df, col1, val1, col2, val2){
  new_cols <- df[,c(col1, col2)]
  omit <- na.omit(new_cols)
  data1 <- omit[omit[,1] == val1,]
  data2 <- omit[omit[,2] == val2,]
  print(nrow(data2)/nrow(data1))
}
fun(jugs, "Place", "UK", "Price", 10)
```

And if I understand what you're trying to do, it may be easier to avoid creating multiple dataframes that you don't need and just use counts instead.

```
fun <- function(df, col1, val1, col2, val2){
  new_cols <- df[,c(col1, col2)]
  omit <- na.omit(new_cols)
  n1 <- sum(omit[,1] == val1)
  n2 <- sum(omit[,2] == val2)
  print(n2/n1)
}
fun(jugs, "Place", "UK", "Price", 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write this function as follows:

```
fun <- function(df,T,a,R,b) {
    data <- na.omit(df[c(T,R)]);
    sum(data[[R]]==b)/sum(data[[T]]==a);
};
```

As you can see, you can combine the first two lines into one, because in your code `col` was not reused anywhere. Secondly, since you only care about the number of rows of the two subsets of the intermediate data.frame, you don't actually need to construct those two data.frames; instead, you can just compute the logical vectors that result from the two comparisons, and then call `sum()` on those logical vectors, which naturally treats `FALSE` as 0 and `TRUE` as 1.

Demo:

```
fun <- function(df,T,a,R,b) { data <- na.omit(df[c(T,R)]); sum(data[[R]]==b)/sum(data[[T]]==a); };
df <- data.frame(place=c(rep(c('p1','p2'),each=4),NA,NA), price=c(10,10,20,NA,20,20,20,NA,20,20), stringsAsFactors=F );
df;
##    place price
## 1     p1    10
## 2     p1    10
## 3     p1    20
## 4     p1    NA
## 5     p2    20
## 6     p2    20
## 7     p2    20
## 8     p2    NA
## 9   <NA>    20
## 10  <NA>    20
fun(df,'place','p1','price',20);
## [1] 1.333333
```